# python suds soap call Start and end tag names don't match

Tags: python, soap

I'm a newb when it comes to soap, but here is what I have. If I make a soap call with perl's SOAP::Lite library, everything is cool. When I make the same call with suds, I get an error from the server.

Here is the working xml generated by the perl call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope 
 soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:urn="urn:webservicesapi" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <urn:getChassis xsi:nil="true" />
    </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

Making the same call with suds, I get this xml generated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="urn:webservicesapi" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <ns0:Body>
        <ns1:getChassis/>
    </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The error produced with the server is: `<ErrorCode>43</ErrorCode><Description>Start and end tag names don't match</Description>`

If I use a soap plugin with my browser, I can replicate this. If I change the body to:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <urn:getChassis xsi:nil="true" />
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

The call works just fine.

So, I either need to know how to change the prefix for Body and urn: or I need to understand why the Start and end tag names don't match?

I understand I can use from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin to manipulate the xml before it is sent, but I am at a loss here.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Got it to work.

```
class EnvelopeFixer(MessagePlugin): 
    def marshalled(self, context): 
    context.envelope.getChild('ns0:Body').setPrefix('ns1')
```

Then I called the plugin when creating the client object

```
client = Client(WSDL_LOCATION, transport=t, location=url, plugins=[EnvelopeFixer()])
```